# React & React-router async components mounted multiple times (componentDidMount called many times)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-router, react-router-v4

I am using Webpack 3.7.1 and React 15.6.1 and I am loading different components dynamically.

### What i did

- Using **AsyncComponent** and **import()** to generate the chunks and load components asynchronously
- **Configured** the webpack.config file properly so that the chunks are created (code splitting)

### The issue

- The components are rerendered (mounted) multiple times. If I console log something in any of the componentDidMount() of any components, it appears in my console 2 or more times !It was not doing so before : when I was just importing normally the component ...

### The behaviour before I change to async components

- The components were loaded correctly and mounted only one time ...

### My Webpack.config file

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  entry: {
    app:"./src/index.js",
    vendor: [
      "axios",
      "react",
      "react-dom",
      "react-redux",
      "react-router",
      "react-router-dom",
      "redux"
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/views',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[chunkhash].chunk.js',
    publicPath: "/views/"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /pdfmake.js$/]
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: "json-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: "vendor",
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename:  __dirname + "/views/index.ejs",
      template: __dirname + "/views/template.ejs",
      inject: 'body',
      chunks: ['vendor', 'app'],
      chunksSortMode: 'manual'
    }),
    new PreloadWebpackPlugin({
      rel: "preload",
      include: ["vendor", "app"]
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
  ]
};
```

### My AppContainer.js file

```
 /**
 * General container of the website
 */
class AppContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("MOUNTING APP CONTAINER")
  }



  render() {
    const HomePage = AsyncComponent(() =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName:"HomePage"  */ "../components/homepage/homepage")
    );


    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The component itself is more complicated (doing API calls and there are more routes) but simplified it here for stack purposes ;)

### My AsyncComponent.js file

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default function asyncComponent(importComponent) {
    class AsyncComponent extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          component: null
        };
      }

      async componentDidMount() {
        const { default: component } = await importComponent();

        this.setState({
          component: component
        });
      }

      render() {
        const C = this.state.component;

        return C ? <C {...this.props} /> : null;
      }
    }

    return AsyncComponent;
  }
```

I guess the issue comes from the AsyncComponents/chunks generation as I did not have this issue before using AsyncCOmponents and splitting my code in chunks... But I don't get where it is coming from exactly

## Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving the declaration of `HomePage` outside of `render`. `render` can be called any number of times, and each component that is returned will look different to React.

```
/**
* General container of the website
*/
const HomePage = AsyncComponent(() =>
  import(/* webpackChunkName:"HomePage"  */ "../components/homepage/homepage")
);

class AppContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("MOUNTING APP CONTAINER")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In general, I advise against doing asynchronous work inside React components. Your rendering layer should be synchronous in order to have a predictable life cycle for your UI.

Comment: Of course !! How didn't I think about that :o Thank you !!